# Term for strong, forceful mode of speech

Tags: single-word-requests

How would I best describe a mode of speech that is strong and forceful, especially when voicing a complaint?  I’m looking to strengthen this sentence, ideally by getting rid of the adverb construction:

> She **complained loudly** about the bad customer service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could say "She ***railed*** against the low quality customer service."

Comment: http://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/rail.php I would understand the meaning but have never heard it in actual use

Comment: @mpl: I have, often (seen). "Railed" is fine, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I would say "She *ranted* about the bad customer service."

Answer (score 2):

Informal: She bitched about the bad customer service

Synonym: She bemoaned the bad customer service

Answer (score 2):

I will throw in *bluster* for good measure.

> She blustered about the bad customer service.

- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bluster#Verb):

  > To speak or protest loudly.
- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bluster):

  > to talk or act with noisy swaggering threats
- The American Heritage Dictionary:

  > a. To speak in a loudly arrogant or bullying manner.
  >   b. To brag or make loud, empty threats.

Comment: "Bluster" has a sense of her complaints and threats being empty and ineffective ("more bark than bite"), which may be appropriate depending on the situation.

Comment: Not to mention anyone under 50 will have a hard time understanding that ;)